# delete unused lines of XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

i need do delete the lines that start with server,name,address,port,month,/server. How can i delete them in PHP. I hava no Idea how to delete them. Is there a simple Way to delete them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
    <name> Vote Statistic Number 4</name>
    <address>domain.tld</address>
    <port>1111</port>
    <month>201402</month>
    <voters>
                <voter>
            <nickname>Username 1</nickname>
            <votes>2</votes>
        </voter>
                <voter>
            <nickname>Username 2</nickname>
            <votes>1</votes>
        </voter>
                <voter>
            <nickname>Username 3</nickname>
            <votes>1</votes>
        </voter>
            </voters>
</server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unset to delete the records, job.xml file contains your xml data

```
<?php 

if (file_exists ( 'job.xml' )) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file ( 'job.xml' );   

    foreach ( $xml->voters->voter as $user ) {
        echo 'Nickname: ' . $user->nickname . '<br>';
        echo 'votes: ' . $user->votes . '<br><br>';
    }
} else {
    exit ( "Datei $xmlFile kann nicht geöffnet werden." );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. now i have nearly every tag i want to remove removed. Only the <server> and </server> tag i don't get removed. when i use unset($xml->server); both tags are still there.

Comment: server is the root node xml is traveled from there only. You can't delete the origin. If you have more than one entry like <server></server><server></server> then it's possible by pointing the index

Comment: Can you then show me how i can modify the following to work with the server tags?
I only get it working if the server tags are removed.


<?php
 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

if (file_exists($xmlFile)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

foreach ( $xml->voter as $user )  {  
           echo 'Nickname: ' . $user->nickname . '<br>';  
           echo 'votes: ' . $user->votes . '<br><br>';  
        }  
} 
else 
{
    exit("Datei $xmlFile kann nicht geöffnet werden.");
}
?>